# Centering Target Word in Elasticsearch Highlighted Snippets

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following configuration set for my elasticsearch highlighting query:

```
"highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "text": {
        "type": "plain",
        "boundary_chars": ".?!",
        "fragment_size": 600,
        "number_of_fragments": 3,
        "boundary_scanner": "sentence",
        "boundary_max_scan": 600,
        "highlight_query": {
          "match_phrase": {
            "text": {
              "query": "Elon",
              "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "pre_tags": [
      "<"
    ],
    "post_tags": [
      ">"
    ]
  }
```

The query works and returns a snippet with the target word . However, sometimes the target word is not in the middle of the snippet and appears either very close to the end or very close to the beginning, which does not provide sufficient context.

Q1: Is there a way to ensure that the target word within the highlighted snippet occurs as close to the center as possible?

Q2: I have tried lowering the number_of_fragments based on a ChatGPT suggestion, and while I see some improvement, I still need to consider other examples within a document. Is there a way to set "number_of_fragments": 1 and ensure that different queries return a random occurrence of the target word rather than the first occurrence? This would help avoid unnecessarily cutting down my documents.

Best,
Andy